# JavaScript associate array

Tags: javascript, associative-array

In Python I could do something like `myMap = {key: [value1, value2]}` and then access the `value2` using `myMap[key][1]`

Can I do something like this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Well, you can do this:

```
var myMap = { key: [ value1, value2 ] };
var array = myMap.key; // or myMap["key"]
```

JavaScript doesn't have an "associative array" type, one that combines "map" behavior with array behavior like keeping track of the number of properties. Thus the common thing to do is use a plain object. In modern JavaScript now (2017), there's an explicit `Map` facility that allows keys to be of any type, not just strings as when using simple objects.

JavaScript is a little bit silly about the object literal notation, in that it won't let you use reserved words for keys unless you quote them:

```
var myMap = { 'function': 'hello world' };
```

The quote syntax allows any string to be used as a property name. To access such properties, you'd use the `[ ]` operator

```
console.log(myMap["function"]); // "hello world"
```

Comment: you declared an object not array!

Comment: @SuhaybKharabsheh ?? Right? JavaScript arrays should not be used when you want non-numeric property names (unless you have a really good reason).

Comment: How do the two approaches scale (say to 10,000 or 1,000,000 elements)? E.g. for insertion and lookup? Is there any difference? E.g. [quadratic behavior](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) would put on a (practical) upper limit on the number of elements.

Comment: @PeterMortensen well property lookup and more generally management in plain JavaScript objects is, as you might imagine, *highly* optimized.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, and the syntax is almost the same too.

```
var myMap = {key: ["value1", "value2"]};
alert(myMap["key"][1]); // Pops up an alert with the word "value2"
```

You can also use the following notation:

```
myMap.key[1]
```

Answer (score 8):

It is indeed.

```
var myMap = {london: ['clapham', 'chelsea'], bristol:['clifton', 'redland']}

alert(myMap.london[0]);
alert(myMap['bristol'][1]);
```

See this example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swaff/55YTL/)

Answer (score 5):

Short answer... yes...

```
var m = { Foo : ["Bar", "Baz"] };

alert(m.Foo[0]);
alert(m["Foo"][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map:

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set('key','Value');
var res = myMap.get('key');

console.log(var); // Result is: 'Value'
```