# How to declare Javascript array with numeric keys (like php does)?

Tags: javascript, php

What I do in php:

```
$arr = [1=>'a', 3=>'b', 2017=>'zzzzZZZZ'];
```

What I konw in js:

```
var arr = [];
arr[1] = 'a';
arr[3] = 'b';
arr[2017] = 'zzzzZZZZ';
```

Comment: not sure what your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would make an array of length `2018` since the largest array index defined is `2017` and the remaining undefined elements are treated as `undefined`.

```js
var arr = [];
arr[1] = 'a';
arr[3] = 'b';
arr[2017] = 'zzzzZZZZ';

console.log(arr.length, arr);
```

---

In  JavaScript, there is no associative array instead there is  [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers) for key-value pair of data.

```
var obj = {
    1 : 'a',
    3 : 'b',
    2017 : 'zzzzZZZZ'
}
```

```js
var obj = {
  1: 'a',
  3: 'b',
  2017: 'zzzzZZZZ'
}

console.log(obj);
```

Refer :  [javascript Associate array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434187/javascript-associate-array)

Comment: I guess you should also include **why** as well.

Comment: Very odd that I can't use `obj.1` to get the value but `obj[1]` or `obj['1']`. Seems that JS object stores data as array, and the most basic way to fetch data is also array. In the meanwhile, array act like restricted object.

Comment: @bijiDango : that's because the property name starts with a name so you can't use dot notation ...... check the docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation